# OrderBy not Fresh when change the value of the key

Tags: angularjs, array-filter

I want to change the order of some objects, that I already filtering by a key of the same object, so..

I do the thing..

```
    /**
     * Direction
     * @param blockIndex
     * @param direction
     */
    $scope.moveBlock = function(blockIndex,direction){
        var block = $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex];

        if(direction === 'up'){
            var newOrder = $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex-1];
            if(newOrder){
                newOrder.order = newOrder.order + 1;
                block.order = block.order - 1;
            }
            return;
        }

        if(direction === 'down'){
            var newOrder = $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex+1];
            if(newOrder){
                newOrder.order = newOrder.order - 1;
                block.order = block.order + 1;
            }
        }
    };
```

And html..

```
<div class="block__wrapper" ng-repeat="(blockIndex, block) in data.blocks  | toArray:false | orderBy: 'block.order' : false">{{block.order}}</div>
```

But doesnt work, the order value change but seems that the orderBy filter not refresh or listen that value..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this, change the content of each object index...

Like this:

```
/**
     * Direction
     * @param blockIndex
     * @param direction
     */
    $scope.moveBlock = function(blockIndex,direction){

        var block = {};
        var upBlock = {};

        if(direction === 'up'){
            var nextIndex = blockIndex-1;
            if($scope.data.blocks[nextIndex]){
                angular.copy($scope.data.blocks[blockIndex],block);
                angular.copy($scope.data.blocks[nextIndex],upBlock);
                $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex] = block;
                $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex].order = $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex].order - 1;
                $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex] = upBlock;
                $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex].order = $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex].order + 1;
            }
            return;
        }

        if(direction === 'down'){
            var nextIndex = blockIndex+1;
            if($scope.data.blocks[nextIndex]){
                angular.copy($scope.data.blocks[blockIndex],block);
                angular.copy($scope.data.blocks[nextIndex],upBlock);
                $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex] = block;
                $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex].order = $scope.data.blocks[nextIndex].order + 1;
                $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex] = upBlock;
                $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex].order = $scope.data.blocks[blockIndex].order - 1;
            }
        }
    };
```